# Peformance timing API inconsistancy

Tags: javascript, performance, api, navigation

I am trying to track time spent on network for a page load using navigaiton API. I am planning to use below formula

Network time = (responseEnd – fetchStart) – ( responseStart – requestStart).(responseStart – requestStart) would be time taken by server to send first byte of response to browser after receiving request. Is my understanding of the API correct?

Also when i tried to get these data, i get same value for everything till responseEnd.

```js
window.onload = function(){  
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("navigationStart : "+ (performance.timing.navigationStart));
        console.log("fetchStart: "+ (performance.timing.fetchStart));
        console.log("requestStart: "+  (performance.timing.requestStart));       
        console.log("responseStart : "+ (performance.timing.responseStart));       
        console.log("responseEnd : "+ (performance.timing.responseEnd));       
        console.log("domComplete : "+ (performance.timing.domComplete));       
        console.log("loadEventStart : "+ (performance.timing.loadEventStart));       
        console.log("LoadEventEnd : "+ (performance.timing.loadEventEnd));      
        console.log("now: "+ (Date.now()));
        console.log("frame count is "+ (frames.length));
    }, 0);
}
```

Below is the output

```
navigationStart : 1543517910446
fetchStart: 1543517910446
requestStart: 1543517910446
responseStart : 1543517910446
responseEnd : 1543517910446
domComplete : 1543517912670
loadEventStart : 1543517912670
LoadEventEnd : 1543517912908
now: 1543517912936
frame count is 0
```